# Should I turn off lazy loading in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, lazy-loading

So I've been getting this feeling that I should turn off lazy loading, for two reasons:

1. queries become non-atomic, so could result in concurrency errors.
2. me or another programmer could end up causing a huge performance impediment.

Of course, both of these problems can be avoided as long as we're careful, but it seems a bit of an unnecessary risk in projects where performance is somewhat important.

As a side note, I found it weird that 1-* relationship properties become `null` rather than throwing an exception when you access them with lazy loading off. I want to go back and do everything in single queries, but I'm worried that I might overlook a bug where I'm interpreting a not-yet-loaded 0-* relationship as being `null`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turn off lazy loading if your worried about performance, if you're not, don't.

Personally, we turn off lazy loading, and **explicitly** allow the inclusion of navigational properties via the interface contract for our repositories, e.g:

```
ICollection<Person> FindSingle(int personId, string[] includeAssociations);
```

So we then *eager-load* the navigational properties ONLY if the calling code specifically asks for it. It's like saying to the code: "Hey, if you want extra information about this T, then ASK for it, otherwise you ain't gettin it!".

As for the 1-*, of course the properties are null. Navigational properties are generally implemented as `ICollection<T>` on the objects, so if there is nothing there, a collection isn't instantiated.

You *could* counteract this effect by creating an empty collection, rather than a null one when you execute your queries. However, i prefer a null collection to an instantiated one with 0 items.

Comment: That's an awesome idea, passing in the includes as a string[]. Regarding the null references, I actually meant 1-0 relations, that is, a reference to zero or one object. I think those can be ambiguous. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. Also, with the includes - you can add a bit of type-safety to the normally hardcoded `.Include` code, by passing an array of `enum` instead of strings. Then create a extension method for that enum which converts the enum to a `.Include` string. This is what we do. So our code looks like: `repository.FindSingle(1, PersonAssociations.Orders)`. Just a bonus tip, free of charge :)

Comment: Aye, I was thinking that, but I find myself being lazy about it because EF will throw an exception if you give it an incorrect argument anyway.

Comment: more of a reason to use enums. if you pass in `repository.FindSingle(1, "Orderz")` (note typo), it will die very late (ef exception). whereas if you have enums, you can avoid this (i throw custom exceptions before i attempt to do any db-work). anyway, it was just a tip. happy ef-ing! :)

Comment: I've never heard of anyone who preferred a null reference to an empty collection. It seems crazy to me... by using an empty collection, you simplify code a lot by assuming that it can never be null. Every recommendation I've seem and every library uses the empty collection approach because it is much more robust. [Related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969993/is-it-better-to-return-null-or-empty-collection).