# IEnumerable<T> null coalescing Extension

Tags: c#, extension-methods, ienumerable, null-coalescing

I frequently face the problem to check whether an `IEnumerable<T>` is null before iterating over it through foreach or LINQ queries, then I often come into codes like this:

```
var myProjection = (myList ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>()).Select(x => x.Foo)...
```

Hence, I thought to add this extension-method to an Extensions class:

```
public static class MyExtensions 
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> AsEmptyIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return source ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }
}
```

A little issue comes immediately in my mind looking at this code, i.e., given the *"instance-methods aspect"* of extension-methods, it should be implemented as a mere static method, otherwise something like this would be perfectly legal:

```
IEnumerable<int> list = null;
list.AsEmptyIfNull();
```

Do you see any other drawback in using it ?
Can such extension leading to some kind of bad-trend in the developer(s), if massively used?

---

**Bonus question:**

Can you suggest a better name to it ?  `:)`
(English is not my first language, then I'm not so good in naming...)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem?  Wouldn't you want that to be legal?  That would be legal with a static method also, but I thought that the whole point was to *make* that legal, which is true using an extension or static method.

Comment: @recursive: did you refer to the "little-issue" part or to the whole question ? If it's the former, I just think that reading the code could be a bit strange for "instance-methods accustomed" people. If the latter, well my question is exactly about the correctness to spread such an extension method (for example in a company-shared utilities assembly) because could lead to bad behaviours...

Comment: When using this extension, if the type is not inferred, try adding `.AsEnumerable()` before `.AsEmptyIfNull()`. Also, I prefer to call the method `EmptyIfNull` because `As` implies casting, which does not take place here. `DefaultIfEmpty` is not named `AsDefaultIfEmpty` either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Methods that return an `IEnumerable<T>` should return an empty one, instead of null. So you wouldn't need this.

See this question : [Is it better to return null or empty collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969993/is-it-better-to-return-null-or-empty-collection)

Otherwise, your code seems ok.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but not always you can change the code to get this result (e.g. when using API). To give a real example, try to serialize an empty list with protobuf, then deserialize it: you will get null :)

Answer (score 3):

It's generally a bad idea to return a `null` instead of an empty sequence if you can control it. This is self-explanatory if you consider that when someone is asked to produce a collection, returning `null` is not like saying "the collection is empty" but "there is no such collection at all".

If you own the methods returning the enumerables, then returning an empty `IEnumerable` (which can even be a special purpose readonly static object if it might be returned a lot) is the way to go, period.

If you are forced to use a bad-mannered library that has the habit of returning `null` in such cases, then this an extension method might be a solution, but again I wouldn't prefer it. It's probably better to wrap the bad-mannered methods in your own versions that do the coalescing where people won't see it. This way you get both the convenience of always having an enumerable instead of `null` and the correctness of not supporting the "return null" paradigm.

Comment: Yes, probably the best thing to do is to wrap bad-mannered libraries. Anyway, create this kind of extension doesn't seem so harmful, does it ?

Comment: @digEmAll: The harm is only that people who see it might think that it's OK for methods to return `null` instead of empty collections and write their own such methods, which would perpetuate the problem. Other than that, I don't see any harm.