# This LINQ statement crashes if one of the Properties is NULL. How can I fix this?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following linq statement which works great, when each `gameServer` in the list has a collection of `connectedClients`.

but when the `connectedClient` is `null`, the query crashes.

How can I prevent this from crashing?

```
var connectedClients = (from x in gameServers
                        from y in x.ConnectedClients
                        select new
                        {
                            x.Name,
                            x.GameType,
                            ConnectedClients = new
                            {
                                y.ClientName,
                                y.ConnectedOn,
                                y.ClientIpAddressAndPort
                            }
                        }).ToList();
```

and..

```
public class GameServer
{
    public int Id;
    public ICollection<Client> ConnectedClients;
    ...
}
```

Comment: `where y != null`? It seems too easy, I must have wrongly understood your question.

Comment: I don't see a variable called `connectedClient`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Personally I would change your code such that `ConnectedClients` is **empty** rather than `null` when there are no connected clients (see eg [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969993/is-it-better-to-return-null-or-empty-collection) ).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it is null, use a value that isn't null instead:

```
var connectedClients = (
    from x in gameServers
    from y in x.ConnectedClients ?? Enumerable.Empty<Client>()
    // ...
```

The `??` is called [the null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

Comment: now that's tricky :) :) :) I'm a fan of `??` .. use it all the time .. didn't think of using it, that way!

Answer (score 7):

add a where to check for null before second from

```
var connectedClients = (from x in gameServers
                        where x.ConnectedClients != null
                        from y in x.ConnectedClients
                        select new
                        {
                            x.Name,
                            x.GameType,
                            ConnectedClients = new
                            {
                                y.ClientName,
                                y.ConnectedOn,
                                y.ClientIpAddressAndPort
                            }
                        }).ToList();
```

Comment: @Pure.Krome yea you can do that. Give it a shot.

Comment: +1 because this could be just as important to people with similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<GameServer> gameServesWIthConnectedClients = from x in gameServers 
                       where x.ConnectedClients != null  
                       select x;

var connectedClients = from y in gameServesWIthConnectedClients
                       select
                           new
                               {
                                   y.Name,
                                   y.GameType,
                                   ConnectedClients =
                           new
                               {
                                   y.ConnectedClients.ClientName,
                                   y.ConnectedClients.ConnectedOn,
                                   y.ConnectedClients.ClientIpAddressAndPort
                               }
                               };
connectedClients = connectedClients.ToList();
```