# ASP.NET MVC - bind empty collection when parameter is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've couple of action methods with parameters of IList type.

```
public ActionResult GetGridData(IList<string> coll)
{
}
```

The default behavior is when no data are passed to action method the parameter is null.

Is there any way to get an empty collection rather then null application wide ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you could either do this:

```
coll = coll ?? new List<string>();
```

Or you would need to implement a ModelBinder that will create an empty list instead of returning null. E.g.:

```
public EmptyListModelBinder<T> : DefaultModelBinder
{
  public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) 
  {
    var model = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext) ?? new List<T>();
  }
}
```

And wired up as:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(IList<string>), new EmptyListModelBinder<string>());
```

I'd probably stick with the argument check though...

Comment: Why would you stick with null checking ? It's a best practice to return empty collection instead of null.

Comment: Why do you think that? What if there is a difference between what `null` represents as to what an empty list represents? What happens in your unit tests for your controller if you pass in null? They will fail. You've got a public method, this forms part of your API, which means you should be argument checking those inputs. I don't remember any guidelines stating that an empty list is better than null...

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969993/is-it-better-to-return-null-or-empty-collection

Comment: You're not **returning** anything..., you're checking an **input** argument.

Comment: Hmm you right, but in my case is this agrument used in many action methods in the same manner, so It looks to me like violation of the DRY principle.

Answer (score 1):

simply do it yourself

```
public ActionResult GetGridData(IList<string> coll)
{
    if(coll == null)
        coll = new List<String>();
    //Do other stuff
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work, because `new List<string>()` is not a compile time constant.

Comment: Removed the first solution to avoid confusion.

Comment: I'm looking for an application wide solution,don't want to check for null values in every action method.