# Check is a Collection Object is Null in Java

Tags: java, spring

I have a Collection Object with structure like this:

```
[
  {
    "maBN": 8,
    "address": "American",
    "_type": "Person",
    "name": "Anna Johnson",
    "parent_of": [
      {
        "maBN": 10,
        "address": "American",
        "_type": "Person",
        "name": "Abraham Napoleon",
        "parent_of.type": "natural",
        "_id": 63
      },
      {
        "maBN": 11,
        "address": "American",
        "_type": "Person",
        "name": "William Napoleon",
        "parent_of.type": "natural",
        "_id": 64
      }
    ],
    "_id": 61
  }
]
```

I want to check if it null like this:

```
[
  {}
]
```

This is my function to check it:

```
public Collection<Object> getFamilyTree(@RequestParam Long id, @RequestParam String gender) {
        if (personService.getFamilyTree(id,gender).toArray().length!=0)
        {
            return personService.getFamilyTree(id, gender);
        }
        else{
            return personService.getFamilyTree2Gen(id,gender);
        }
    }
```

With personService.getFamilyTree and personService.getFamilyTree2Gen return a Collection

What should I do? Thanks a lot and sorry for my bad English!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best practice to validate null and empty collection in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721076/best-practice-to-validate-null-and-empty-collection-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Use below utility method to know if the collection null or empty.

```
public static <T> boolean isEmpty(Collection<T> c) {
   if (c == null) {
       return true;
   } else {
       return c.size() == 0;
   }
}

public static <T> boolean isNotEmpty(Collection<T> c) {
   return !isEmpty(c);
}
```

**Then Write in your code like this**

```
Collection<Object> familyTree = personService.getFamilyTree(id, gender);
if (isNotEmpty(familyTree)) {
    return familyTree;
} else {
    return personService.getFamilyTree2Gen(id,gender);
}
```

Comment: A more idiomatic way to check of a non-null collection is empty would be `c.isEmpty()`. I would hesitate to call these methods "is empty" and "is not empty", given that there is already a well-known notion of "emptiness" of Java collections: "is null or empty" would be better.

Comment: @AndyTurner I agree with you. but calling `c.isEmpty()` on a null collection will produce NullPointerException which I guess is not desired in this case.

Comment: hence "on a non-null collection". Don't use size, use isEmpty.

Comment: this is the implementation of isEmpty() from java.util `public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size() == 0; }`

Comment: yes; but consider why there is a need for the `isEmpty()` method as well: the `isEmpty()` method allows for implementations of `Collection` to short-circuit size evaluation, e.g. if would require traversing a linked list.