# Java own List function for .NullOrEmpty

Tags: java, list, kotlin, kotlin-extension

In Java you have a lot of List Functions. e.g: List.size(), List.isEmpty()...

Is it possible to make my own Function like List.nullOrEmpty() and how can i do this?

i create a class who do this.

```html
public class ListUtil { 
    public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(final List list) { 
        return list == null || list.isEmpty(); 
    }
 }
```

but here i need to call ListUtil.isNullOrEmpty(myList) to check.

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12721103/6754986

Answer (score 1):

There is already [`isNullOrEmpty`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/is-null-or-empty.html) function in **Kotlin** for Collections. It is defined like the following:

```
@SinceKotlin("1.3")
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T> Collection<T>?.isNullOrEmpty(): Boolean {
    contract {
        returns(false) implies (this@isNullOrEmpty != null)
    }

    return this == null || this.isEmpty()
}
```

So if you have an object of type `List?` you can use it like the following:

```
val list: List<String>? = ... // somehow get the list
if (list.isNullOrEmpty()) {
    // do something when the list is null or empty
}
```

---

If you want to create your own function for the `List` object in **Kotlin** you can create an [**extension function**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html) on `List` type:

```
fun <T> List<T>?.hasAtLeastTwoElements(): Boolean = this != null && size >= 2
```

And then you can use it:

```
val list: List<String>? = ... // somehow get the list
if (list.hasAtLeastTwoElements()) {
    // do something when the list has at least two elements
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the function `List.isEmpty()` you will check/avoid the NullPointerException.

But to answer your question, yes, you can make your own function.

My question to you is what do you want that function to check? Maybe Java has already a function that does what you want to implement in the function