# Cannot assign null to anonymous property of type array

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

I have any array of (`Pilot`) objects with a (`Hanger`) property, which may be null, which itself has a (`List<Plane>`) property. For testing purposes, I want to simplify and 'flatten' this to an anonymous object with properties `PilotName` (string) and `Planes` (array) but not sure how to handle a null `Hanger` property or an empty `PlanesList`.

(Why anonymous objects? Because the objects of the API I'm testing are read only and I want the test to be 'declarative': self contained, simple and readable... but I'm open to other suggestions. Also I'm trying to learn more about LINQ.)

example

```
class Pilot
{
    public string Name;
    public Hanger Hanger;
}

class Hanger
{
    public string Name;
    public List<Plane> PlaneList;
}

class Plane
{
    public string Name;
}

[TestFixture]
class General
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var pilots = new Pilot[]
        {
            new Pilot() { Name = "Higgins" },
            new Pilot()
            {
                Name = "Jones", Hanger = new Hanger()
                {
                    Name = "Area 51",
                    PlaneList = new List<Plane>()
                    {
                        new Plane { Name = "B-52" },
                        new Plane { Name = "F-14" }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var actual = pilots.Select(p => new
        {
            PilotName = p.Name,
            Planes = (p.Hanger == null || p.Hanger.PlaneList.Count == 0) ? null : p.Hanger.PlaneList.Select(h => ne
            {
                PlaneName = h.Name
            }).ToArray()
        }).ToArray();

        var expected = new[] {
            new { PilotName = "Higgins", Planes = null },
            new
            {
                PilotName = "Jones",
                Planes = new[] {
                    new { PlaneName = "B-52" },
                    new { PlaneName = "F-14" }
                }
            }
        };

        Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected));
    }
```

The immediate problem is that the line `expected... Planes = null` errors with,

> Cannot assign  to anonymous type property but admit the underlying problem may be that using `null` in `actual` is using `null` is not the best approach in the first place.

Any ideas how to either assign the null array in `expected` or take a different approach than `null` in `actual`?

Comment: The primary issue with your updated example is because you're checking equality between an enumerator (the `WhereSelectArrayIterator` created by the `pilots.Where` call) and an array.  You can use `ToArray()` at the end of the `Where` clause to force it into an array.

Comment: To the wider problem I'd say two things: Firstly, A very good change to consider would be making (eg) `Planes` be an **empty collection** rather than **`null`**, when there aren't any items. It's much easier to deal with; [here's some background reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969993). Secondly, I suspect you're going to have to make the equality check between actual and expected more 'intelligent'; ie, it's going to have to dive into the objects and collections, and use something like `SequenceEqual`.

Comment: @AndrasZoltan: You are right, question now corrected :)

Comment: @AakashM:  empty collection: I did the background reading and I agree but I can't get the required change right within my code. Can you suggest a fix? Thanks. p.s. you are correct about the Assert too :)

Comment: Hmm, of course with a sometimes-`null` `Hanger` it's harder... maybe [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern#C.23) for that. For collections, just return `Enumerable.Empty<type>` rather than `null`.

Comment: @AakashM: I've appended my attempt to the end of the question but has a compile error. Ccan you suggest a fix? Thanks again.

Comment: @petemoloy With that, the two objects in the array are actually different types, because while `Enumerable.Empty<string>()` and `List<string>` both implement `IEnumerable<string>`, they're not the exact same type. Put `.AsEnumerable()` after the `new List<>()` and it compiles

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There are two things happening:

Firstly, when you construct an instance of an anonymous type using `new { Name = Value}`, in order to build the type the compiler needs to be able to work out the **type** of `Value`. Just `null` on its own doesn't have a type, so the compiler wouldn't know what type to give your `Planes` member.

Now, if you were using a named type for the value, you could just say `(type)null` and be done, BUT because you want an array of another anonymous type, there's no way to *refer* to is (it's anonymous!).

So how do you get `null` typed as array of an anonymous type? Well, the C# spec guarantees that anonymous types with members the same names and types (in the same order!) are **unified**; that is, if we say

```
var a = new { Foo = "Bar" };
var b = new { Foo = "Baz" };
```

then `a` and `b` have **the same type**. We can use this fact to get our suitably-typed `null` thus:

```
var array = (new[] { new { PlaneName = "" } });
array = null;
```

It's not pretty but it works - now `array` has the right **type** but a `null` **value**. So this compiles:

```cs
var array = new[] {
  new {
    PlaneName = ""
  }
};
array = null;

var expected = new[] {
  new {
    PilotName = "Higgins",
    Planes = array
  },
  new {
    PilotName = "Higgins",
    Planes = new[] {
      new {
        PlaneName = "B-52"
      },
      new {
        PlaneName = "F-14"
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: that's pretty sweet (if a little odd too!) - I'd read about that before but never found a use for it.

Comment: An alternative is to inline `new[] { new { PlaneName = "" } }.Take(0).ToArray()`

Answer (score 83):

You have to use a ***typed*** *null*:

```
(List<Plane>)null
```

Or

```
(Plane[])null
```

Otherwise the compiler has no idea what type you want the anonymous type's member to be.

**Update**
As @AakashM has rightly pointed out - this solves your problem of assigning a `null` to an anonymous member - but doesn't actually compile - and if it did it wouldn't allow you to refer to these members.

A fix would be to do this (unfortunately both the `null` and the anonymous `Planes` array will need casting:

```
var expected = new[] {
  new { 
          PilotName = "Higgins", 
          Planes = (IEnumerable)null
      },
  new {
          PilotName = "Higgins", 
          Planes = (IEnumerable)new [] {
                              new { PlaneName = "B-52" },
                              new { PlaneName = "F-14" } 
                          }
      }
};
```

So use `IEnumerable` as the member type.  You could also use `IEnumerable<object>` but the effect will be the same either way.

Or - you could use `IEnumerable<dynamic>` as the common type - this would let you do this:

```
Assert.AreEqual("B-52", expected[1].Planes.First().PlaneName);
```

Comment: ...but now, since OP wants the type to be an array of another anonymous type, there is no way to refer to it.

Comment: Ah that's a good point.  `IEnumerable` might do it then, but it does wipe out any compile-time type knowledge.

Comment: Yes switching to `IEnumerable` would work - but we can fix the test code without changing the code being tested; see my answer.

Comment: Good idea! Thank you Andras

Comment: For the sake of completeness:

`null as Plane[]` would also work.

Answer (score 14):

Just use `default(Plane[])` instead of `null`.