# structure of classes base on a given statement

Tags: c#, oop

I'm trying to understand usage of collection in C# and also doing practice on how to define classes base on a statement given in msdn example since its class is not posted and left to reader. I came up with following classes but need to know if it this is right or wrong:

Statement says:

```
    // ListLeagueList is a list of League objects. 
    // Each League object has a Name and a collection of Division objects. 
    // Each Division has a Name and a collection of Team objects, 
    // and each Team object has a Name.



public class Team
{
    private string teamName;
    public string TeamName
    {
        get { return teamName; }
        set { teamName = value; }
    }
}

public class Division
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public List<Team> DivisionList;
}


public class League
{
    private string Name;
    public string name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    List<Division> DivisionList;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is the structure of classes right? or wrong?    if yes, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: This is not a question, but if you want to know it's right, except for the fact that [Collections should never be null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969993/is-it-better-to-return-null-or-empty-collection), therefore you should change your List fields to properties and make sure they're never null.

Comment: @HighCore I went over the URL you referred but not sure what would be the case of `public static readonly List<Team> TeamList = new List<Team>();`  can you give me an example on this?

Comment: @amitkohan You mean if you should change that into a property? In general I prefer not to expose fields outside classes, but technically it's the same.

Comment: yes, can you show me an example I'm not an expert in it and would love to know it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That appears correct, however you've named a `List<Team>` as `DivisionList`.. I would change it to `TeamList`:

```
public class Division
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Team> TeamList { get; set; } // Change this, because its a List of Teams.
}
```

EDIT:

gilly beat me to the shorthand properties :$

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten your property definitions by using [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx):

```cs
public string Name { get; set; }
```

This way, you don't need the backing field.  If, later on, you need to use a backing field for some reason, add it in at that time.