# How to handle nulls in this LINQ Code using a possible null List?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-entities

I am using MVC3, Razor, C#.

I have a some Razor code which include some LINQ. It tries to get a value from a List. Sometimes the List is null. At present the application is raising a null exception due to this ie "myCustomers" is null.

The code:

```
Model.myCustomers.First().Name
```

Basically "myCustomers" is defined as:

```
public List<Customer> myCustomers
```

And populated by a "LINQ to Entity" Query.

If "myCustomers" is null, how can I ensure the razor code does not crash. I do not want to write lots of "if (Name!=null)" type blocks for each property. I cannot iterate through all the properties due to layout design issues. So I need to alter:

```
Model.myCustomers.First().Name
```

in some way.

Hopefully this question is not too confusing !

many thanks in advance.

EDIT 1

I like the logic with not returning nulls, but empty lists. I tried using something like

```
return this._myCustomers ?? Enumerable.Empty<Customers>().ToList();
```

It would be ideal to have someway to test this in the one line of LINQ in the Razor page for being empty rather than in an "IF" block.

EDIT 2

```
    public static TValue SafeGet<TObject, TValue>(
        this TObject obj,
        Func<TObject, TValue> propertyAccessor)
    {
        return obj == null ? default(TValue) : propertyAccessor(obj);
    }
```

So:

```
   Model.myCustomers.FirstOrDefault().SafeGet(m=>m.Name)
```

Comment: Could myCustomers also be an empty list? If that's possible you'd also have to check for that or else the `First()` will throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Collection or enumerable should never return null value for best practice.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969993/is-it-better-to-return-null-or-empty-collection)

Once you make sure that myCustomers is not null, you will only need to check myCustomers's first item is not null.

```
var customer = Model.myCustomers.FirstOrDefault();
if (customer != null)
{
   var name = customer.Name;
}
```

Comment: I like the logic here, and have added EDIT 1 with code. Just trying to test this "empy" code in the one line rather than an "if" block. Is this not possible? Many thanks.

Comment: `return this._myCustomers ?? new List<Customers>();` is also fine.

Comment: OK, thanks for this. Yes I discovered this. How could I use my one liner in the Razor view which could check for empty lists that this would produce. If found then perhaps write out nothing. I was rather hoping to not use an "if" block, but rather something more succinct?

Comment: I used an extension method that I forgot I had, but originally sourced from SO, so I have posted it under EDIT2. Interestingly, since I was writing a Razor View, there was the option of just creating 2 block of HTML, one with to process when records present and the other when records absent. So clearly a choice between clever LINQ or copy/paste HTML although the later is simple it does seem more duplicated and less eloquent. Thanks again. Learnt much from this question

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot iterate through all the properties due to layout design issues.

I'm not exactly clear on what this means, but could you not do something like this?

```
@if (Model.myCustomers == null || !Model.myCustomers.Any())
{
    <p>No customer found.</p>
}
@else
{
    [ put the markup for each property here ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This did give me the idea of copying and pasting 2 bits of HTML, one for records present, and the other when absent. However the code could get a bit duplicated. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If your collection is not `null`, then in your razon view you can use

```
 Model.myCustomers.Any() ? Model.myCustomers.First().Name : string.Empty;
```

If for some reason you can not avoid your collection to be null, I guess you can do something like this.

```
 Model.myCustomers == null ? string.Empty : Model.myCustomers.Any() 
       ? Model.myCustomers.First().Name : string.Empty;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Totally get the logic. I ended up going with an extension method which makes it more succinct. Thanks again.