# How to filter parent list<> when we apply condition on child list?

Tags: .net, linq, list

How to filter parent list<> when we apply condition on child list ?

```
public class VendorEntities
{
    public int VendorId { get; set; }     
    public string VendorName { get; set; }
    public List<ItemEntities> ItemDealdetails { get; set; }    
}

public class ItemEntities
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
}

List<VendorEntities> objVenderList = new List<VendorEntities>();
objVenderList = objVendorBL.GetVendorName();

var rList = (from a in objVenderList
             from b in a.ItemDealdetails
             where b.ItemName.Contains("Computer")
             orderby a.VendorName descending
             select a).ToList().Distinct();
```

Now i want to search those vendor whose `ItemName` contains `Computer` which is store in Child List `ItemEntities`. How i can do this? Please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Any`:

```
var rList = objVenderList
        .Where(v => v.ItemDealdetails.Any(d => d.ItemName.Contains("Computer")))
        .OrderByDescending(v => v.VendorName)
        .ToList();
```

Note that i've omitted your `Distinct` since it only removes duplicate references anyway until you haven't implemented `IEquatable<T>` or overridden `Equals` + `GetHashCode`.

Here the same in query syntax:

```
var filteredByItemNameComputer = 
    from vendor in objVenderList
    where vendor.ItemDealdetails.Any(d => d.ItemName.Contains("Computer"))
    orderby  vendor.VendorName descending
    select vendor;
var rList=filteredByItemNameComputer.ToList();
```

Comment: I was typing the same thing while you posted. Great minds think alike and all.

Comment: Thanks @Tim , but this code generate a **Object reference**. Error.

Comment: @AjayKumarSantra: then you have another problem. Why is `ItemDealdetails` or `ItemName` null?

Comment: When i convert the result "ToList()" its shows the error , and no the "objVenderList" is not null, but some of the child list "ItemEntities" can return null values.

Comment: @AjayKumarSantra: you haven't mentioned that, then use `.Where(v => v.ItemDealdetails!=null && ...` or in query syntax: `where vendor.ItemDealdetails!=null &&...`

Comment: Thanks @TimSchmelter its working correctly, and sorry for my incomplete question ..

Comment: @AjayKumarSantra: you're welcome. In my opinion it's better to use empty lists instead of null-lists since that causes problems everywhere. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969993/is-it-better-to-return-null-or-empty-collection PS: you might want to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :)

Comment: Ok @TimSchmelter: next time i will use empty lists instead of null lists.. Thank you.