# How to cause a service reference to generate an empty xml tag in soap request for complex object?

Tags: c#, xml, soap, service-reference

I imported a WSDL into my project for a 3rd party system. (The WSDL is a nightmare)

Anyway in order for my request to receive a valid response i have been told by the 3rd party i need to send through an empty object in one of the requests.

Lets assume a valid request looks like the below:

```
<Request>
  <UserID>123456</UserID>
  <ComplexObj/>
</Request>
```

If i send the above XML manually in SOAP UI then I get a valid response. 
However because I'm doing this in C# i have imported the WSDL into visual studio and have a service reference generated i cannot figure out a way for the request to generate the empty ComplexObj.

If i set ComplexObj to null in the code it is not included in the request.
If i create a new instance of the ComplexObj then the request includes all the variables within the ComplexObj which is also invalid.

Comment: Did you try to apply `NonSerializedAttribute` to all the attributes of your ComplexObj ? If it doesn't work maybe you'll have to have to implement your own Custom Serialization methods for this class. More info here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx

Answer (score 1):

HAve you tried to declare ComplexObjproperty to serialize even if it is null. For that you'll need to find the definition of class and add

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
```

for that property. That 'll include it into SOAP request as `<ComplexObj xsi:nil="true" />`

Comment: Im not manually generating the XML. It being generated in the background by the service reference created by the WSDL.

Comment: Helpful but still doesnt work fully. This adds nill="true" to the xml which causes the 3rd party to error. <ComplexObj xsi:nil="true"/>. Ive dropped an email to the 3rd party so see if they can fix their side to be less sensitive.

Comment: Actually, i've looked through couple of post here, and it looks like  your 3rd party is trying to go against best practice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29118057/removing-nill-true-from-wcf-request

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969993/is-it-better-to-return-null-or-empty-collection

Comment: Oh ya they totally are. You should see some of the stuff they have me fudging. Cant wait to get this project out the door. lol