# Which is better return null or empty object?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Which is better return null or empty object?

```
var entity = GetFromDB();
if (entity != null)
{
    var price = entity.Price != null 
        ? PriceDecorator.Decorate(entity.Price) 
        : null;
}

    public class PriceDecorator
 {
     public static string Decorate(decimal? price)
     {
         if (price == null || price == 0)
             return String.Empty;

         return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture , "{0:C}", price);
     }
 }
```

In the above code, sometimes I return null and sometimes I return Sting.Empty, I don't know what to return to indicate 'no data'.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969993/is-it-better-to-return-null-or-empty-collection

Answer (score 4):

It depends:

- When I return `string.Empty` on a property of an object, it means that the **entity does exist**, but the object doesn't have a property or the property is in fact a string with no characters.
- When I return `null` instead of `string.Empty` it means that **the entry/entity doesn't exists**, in other words, there is *no data*