# Better to create an empty list or return null when dealing with a LARGE number of objects per frame in a game?

Tags: collections, null, processing

I'm basically asking which is more costly on the CPU.

The situation is that I have about 40-400 particles on the screen at any one given time.  Each particle has a List of ParticleAI which have an Update() method that returns a List of newly created Particle objects, if any.  Now, since this game is being made for mobile, efficiency on the processor is key.  I was wondering if it is more costly to create something between 100-2000 Lists every frame (at 60FPS) which may be empty, which is the way I have it now, or to return nulls and do a null check for each AI.  For some reason, in my brain it seems constructing a List object would take more processor time than simply returning a null and then doing a boolean check for it.  Am I wrong in my assumption?

I have looked at other similar questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969993/is-it-better-to-return-null-or-empty-collection), but it doesn't seem to answer my question.  I get that best practice is to return empty, but I am not making this game for anyone else to edit, and so I know that a null will never be received unexpectedly.  I need to know in pure processing terms which is better, simply because of the sheer number of particle objects being created at once.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Just realized something which may work better.  Would it be a better idea to (instead of creating a new list and returning it for every particleAI every frame) create each particleAI's return list at construction and then clear it at the beginning of each Update() phase?  That almost seems like it would be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't really going to get a single best answer, because there isn't one. What you do depends entirely on your context. One approach might be best for one person writing one program, but a completely different approach would be better for a different person.

I will say that what you're talking about is called an [object pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern), and that might be a good place to start some research. Java (and therefore Processing) already uses this for `Integers` and `Strings`, and it's a very reasonable thing to implement yourself, especially if you're targeting mobile.

Another thing to keep in mind is that an `ArrayList` uses arrays behind the scenes. By default, an `ArrayList` makes room for 10 objects, so it creates an array with a length of 10. You can change this by using the constructor that takes a capacity. But also keep in mind that as you fill an `ArrayList`, it will allocate space for twice as many objects. So if your capacity is 10, when you hit 10 objects, it'll create a new array with a capacity of 10. (This is very general, but it's another thing worth investigating.)

Other than that, you're going to have to do some profiling. Before you even start asking these types of questions, you have to know the answer to this: how much memory do your objects take up? How much processing time do they take?

Create a simple example program to test out both approaches, and then do some stress testing to get some measurements. But really, it sounds like you might be looking for a problem before you have one. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

If you do find that creating 2000 `List` instances 60 times per second is too much, you might also consider refactoring your approach to be less intensive. I don't really understand why you'd need to have multiple `Lists` for each particle, so there might be a more efficient way to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

As objects are shared, reusing the same list object will not do. Would involve copying.

Null or empty list? Assuming you want to read from and write to the list, null seems ugly. In java a LinkedList would be lighter that an ArrayList, so pick a linked list.

Null would be faster. A read-only, to-be-replaced `Collections.emptyList()` would be a bit safer.

Instead of the data structure of one aspect it might be worthwile considering the algorithmic approach. Spending time on the right relevant things. Queues. Priorities.