# using an IEnumerable list outside of foreach loop

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I am using `IEnumerable` in a for each loop as follows:

```
foreach (IListBlobItem blobItem in container.ListBlobs())
{        
    if (blobItem is CloudBlobDirectory)
    {
        CloudBlobDirectory directory = (CloudBlobDirectory)blobItem;
        IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs = directory.ListBlobs(true);
    }                
}
await ProcessBlobs(blobs);
```

I would like to use `blobs`variable outside of this foreach loop but I get this message: `blobs doesnot exist in the current context`

I decided to define `blobs` outside of the foreach loop:

```
IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs = new IEnumerable<IListBlobItem>;

foreach (IListBlobItem blobItem in container.ListBlobs())
{           
    if (blobItem is CloudBlobDirectory)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(blobItem.Uri);
        CloudBlobDirectory directory = (CloudBlobDirectory)blobItem;
        IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs = directory.ListBlobs(true);                    
    }
}
```

but I get the error: `can not create an instance of the abstract class or interface IEnumerable<IListBlobItem>`

Do you have any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Create a `List<IListBlobItem>`... Also you cannot have declaration twice...

Comment: Try: IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs = null; ...

Comment: IEnumerable is an interface and you can't instantiate an interface. Instead, you can find a class that implements IEnumerable and use that. Maybe use `List`and do `IEnumerable<ILIstBlobItem> blobs = new List<IListBlobItem>();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare `blobs` being an *empty collection*, say, array:

```
   // Empty
   IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs = new IListBlobItem[0];

   foreach (IListBlobItem blobItem in container.ListBlobs())
   {
      if (blobItem is CloudBlobDirectory)
      {
          CloudBlobDirectory directory = (CloudBlobDirectory)blobItem;
          blobs = directory.ListBlobs(true);                    
      }            
   }

   // process either blobs from foreach or an empty collection
   await ProcessBlobs(blobs);
```

Comment: IListBlobItem is interface. `new IListBlobItem` is wrong syntax

Comment: @Roma Ruzich: yes, `new IListBlobItem` is wrong syntax, but `new IListBlobItem[0]` is *not*: it's an *array* of `Length = 0` of `IListBlobItem` items

Comment: Ops, sorry. But, is it better to declare the variable with a default value or not?

Comment: @Roma Ruzich: `default(IEnumerable<IListBlobItem>)` will return `null` which is *not a good practice* in case of collections (empty collection is a better choice)

Comment: Explain, please, why empty collection is better then `null`.

Comment: @Roma Ruzich: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969993/is-it-better-to-return-null-or-empty-collection

Comment: thank you. I read this post. But there is no explanation why empty collection is better. I think that `null` is better because: 1) no place on heap 2) when you try to do some manipulation with `null`-collection you take exception

Comment: @Roma Ruzich: 1. when working with *collection* (often a lot of items), `4` or `8` *bytes* on a heap is not worth be optimized 2. usually, we don't want any `NullReferenceException` to be thrown, but just *return* - if we don't have any blob to process then `await ProcessBlobs(blobs);` shouldn't throw any exception but *do nothing*. `ProcessBlobs` can well be something like `foreach (var blob in blobs) {...}`, if `blobs` is `null` this (quite natural) implementation *crashes* but does as expected in case `blobs` is an empty collection

Comment: @ Dmitry Bychenko, thanks thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Enumerable.Empty<TResult>`, like so:

```
IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs = Enumerable.Empty<IListBlobItem>();
```

This will return an empty, non-null enumerable.

See [.NET API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.empty?view=netcore-3.0)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to create an object of an interface which is impossible. Instead, declare `blobs` as object an then convert it to `IEnumerable<IListBlobItem>`.

```
object blobs = null;

foreach (IListBlobItem blobItem in container.ListBlobs())
{           
    if (blobItem is CloudBlobDirectory)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(blobItem.Uri);
        CloudBlobDirectory directory = (CloudBlobDirectory)blobItem;
        blobs = directory.ListBlobs(true);                    
    }
}
///usage:
///(IEnumerable<IListBlobItem>)blobs
```

Also, you can declare blobs as `IEnumerable<IListBlobItem>` which other answers cover.

Answer (score 1):

Use `default` to get default value. This will return null for reference type

```
IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs = default(IEnumerable<IListBlobItem>);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default

Comment: `default` will return `null`, which is often not a good practice for collections (an empty collection usually is a better choice)

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Set IEnumerable blobs like property in this way:

```
IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs{get;set;}
```