# How To Replace Javascript's forEach With Better Version?

Tags: javascript, foreach

I keep getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null` in my Javascript because I'm not checking for null after a `document.querySelectorAll()` call.

Is there a way to create a special `forEach()` on the Javascript `null` object, and make it do nothing, thereby eliminating the error? Or, can we replace the `forEach()` that I use with `.forEach2()` so that `forEach2()` won't do anything on a `null`?

For example:

```
var $ = s => document.querySelectorAll.bind(document)(s).length > 1 ? document.querySelectorAll.bind(document)(s) : document.querySelector.bind(document)(s);

$('FOOTER EM').forEach(function(el,i){
  console.log(el);
});
```

The above is generating an error for me if there is no EM under FOOTER, such as at runtime I sometimes add some.

Comment: [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) will never return `null`. The only return value is a `NodeList` which can be empty.

Comment: _"The Document method `querySelectorAll()` returns a static (not live) `NodeList` representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors."_ - From the above linked documentation.

Comment: @Andreas maybe it's how I'm really doing it. I'm doing: `var $ = s => document.querySelectorAll.bind(document)(s).length > 1 ? document.querySelectorAll.bind(document)(s) : document.querySelector.bind(document)(s);
`

Comment: myArray||[].forEach(function (value) {
  console.log(value);
});

Comment: What is this `document.querySelectorAll.bind(document)` construct supposed to do/solve? o.O

Comment: @Andreas it slightly simulates the old $ tool of jQuery, which I'm not using here.

Comment: Why do you query the DOM always twice. One time with `.querySelectorAll()` and another one with either `.querySelectorAll()` or `.querySelector()`? o.O Do it once with `.querySelectorAll()` and return the result - which will also fix your problem.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: @Andreas Darn, right. Was testing on IE with a polyfill for Array.from. Sorry.

Comment: _"it slightly simulates the old $"_ - No, it just adds unnecessary steps... `document` won't ever change

Comment: Good read NodeList vs. Array: https://gomakethings.com/converting-a-nodelist-to-an-array-with-vanilla-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to create a special `forEach()` on the Javascript null object, and make it do nothing

Not exactly a special function, you can use an [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) method call for this:

```
$('FOOTER EM')?.forEach(el => console.log(el));
//            ^
```

However, it would be a much better practice to simply not have your `$` function [return `null` instead of an empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969993/1048572):

```
const $ = s => document.querySelectorAll(s);
// or
// const $ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);

for (const el of $('FOOTER EM')) console.log(el);
```