# Return empty List<T> or null when no list items present?

Tags: c#

When I have a method which returns a collection of objects, what I should return if the objects count is zero? `null` or just empty `List<T>`? What is good practice?

```
public List<string> GetPupilsByClass(string className)
{
     ....
}
```

Comment: Review of practices should probably be over at [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: Seems general enough for SO I think.

Comment: @BoltClock Which is why I refrained from flagging it. Still _more_ fitting over there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should functions return null or an empty object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626597/should-functions-return-null-or-an-empty-object)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd definitely return an empty list so methods can still be called on the object without requiring null checks. There's a difference between returning an empty list and returning nothing at all, so the calling code probably isn't expecting to receive a null reference anyway (unless an exception occurs or something).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on a number of factors, but an empty list would be a more *typical* return value, as otherwise the caller must know to perform `null` checking. The main time I'd return a `null` is if it was a method of this style:

```
bool Try*(args, out result)
```

The caller expects (on receiving `false`) not to even *look* at the value of `result`.

If you happen to be returning *arrays*, there is a nice cheat - you can store a zero-length typed array in a static field somewhere are return that. But ultimately an empty list isn't going to be a huge overhead to allocate, so just sent that.

Answer (score 3):

An empty list is what I'd expect as a caller. Null would indicate to me that the "conceptual list" is undefined, like null in a database.

Also, by always returning empty collections rather than null, clients like these will never fail:

```
foreach(var element in obj.Method()) ...
```

Answer (score 3):

According to MS, you should never return a null string or array from a field or property, and I think this could be extended to methods (and may well be, somewhere that I haven't found).

On returning empty arrays:

> String and Array properties should never return a null reference. Null can be difficult to understand in this context.
>
> The general rule is that null, empty string (""), and empty (0 item) arrays should be treated the same way. Return an empty array instead of a null reference.

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2604h5s.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

is this method an ifc method? which means used by external objects not controlled by you?
if the answer yes, then i would return an empty collection, as the caller is not expecting an exception.

if this method is internal and you will be the only user, i would return a null to save the wasted memory allocated for an empty collection and a GC performance hit once you stop using it.

Answer (score 1):

A better practice is to return `IEnumerable<string>`.  Use `yield return` and `yield break` within your method to build up your collection.  In this manner, you postpone the creation of the array.  Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) for more information.  You'll find `IEnumerable` has the benefit that it can be chained within extension methods and linq queries:

```
var results = from x in GetPupilsByClass(className) where x.StartsWith("A");
```

If you absolutely must return a complete list (due to the lazy nature of `yield`), then I would recommend changing your method signature to the following:

```
public bool TryGetPupilsByClass(string className, out ICollection<string> pupils)
```

This technique has three advantages.

1. Your intentions are clear -- pupils will be initialized if the return value is true.  A user of your code does not have to guess which practice you've settled on.
2. You of course will *not* bother allocating a list in the event that the collection is empty, which saves on memory allocations.
3. `ICollection<string>` is strongly typed without revealing the storage mechanism you are using.  Returning concrete classes should be used sparingly.  Alternatives are things like `IList<string>`, `ReadOnlyCollection<string>`, and `IEnumerable<string>`, but the one you choose certainly makes your intentions of what the user can and can not do with the results much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Allways return emty list. And you will avoid the most often happening exception - `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends really on the context in which your code is being used. For most purposes, I return a list of zero objects, and I think it would be best here as well - it is more consistent with your normal results.

Answer (score 0):

I generally follow the Clean Code guidance by R.Martin. It is recommended to return an empty list:

> public List GetPupilsByClass(string className)
>   {
>        ....
>   }

I do it for the following reasons:

1. Caller method does not have to check for null.
2. This method does not have to do error handling.
3. Exceptions will be caught at a higher level method.