# How to handle a method where the parameter is tightly connected to the return value. What if the parameter is null? Java

Tags: java, return

I'm writing a method that should return the first item in an array belonging to a certain user. The class looks like this:

```
 public MailItem getNextMailItem(String who)
 {

         return mailbox.get(who).pollFirst();

 }
```

I need some sort of error handling in case the "who"-parameter is empty or null e.g

```
  if (who != null && who.length() != 0)
```

But what if that turns out to be false?

Comment: This depends on your requirements. The most common strategies are returning null as your MailItem or throwing an exception.

Comment: Of course! Somewhere in my confused mind I thought that returning null would give me an error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning null in the absence of a value would be an obvious solution:

```
public MailItem getNextMailItem(String who){
     MailItem mailItem = null;
     if (who != null && who.length() != 0){
        mailItem = mailbox.get(who).pollFirst();
     } 
     return mailItem;
}
```

But consider this:

If you communicate with null, your return value really is [ambiguous](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained). It can mean a lot of things. Instead, you could use [Guava's Optional](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained#Optional) or the [Null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Using the Null pattern, you would define an instance that has a neutral behavior, possibly in your MailItem interface, and return it in case of the absence of a value:

```
public MailItem getNextMailItem(String who) {
    MailItem mailItem = null;
      if (who != null && who.length() != 0){
         mailbox.get(who).pollFirst();
      } else {
         mailItem = MailItem.NULL_ITEM;
      }
     return mailItem;
}
```

This way - unless an unexpected exception happens - you can always be sure that `getNextMailItem` returns a valid instance of `MailItem`.

Answer (score 1):

your if block is something like that

```
public MailItem getNextMailItem(String who) {
 MailItem item = null;
 if (who != null && who.length() != 0) {
    item = mailbox.get(who).pollFirst();
 } else {
  //show some error message or error log here 
 }
return item;
}
```

on filure your method will return null.

also read this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626597/should-functions-return-null-or-an-empty-object)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to return null. On the other side, check for null and handle accordingly.