# Should I return a null or an empty list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of type entity which get values from a DB via Entity Framework. Should a null result set be returned as null or as an empty list, as below:

```
    private List<Order> _myOrders;
    public List<Order> myOrder
    {
        get
        {
            return this._myOrders ?? new List<Order>();
        }
        set
        {
            this._myOrders = value;
        }
    }
```

Any handling code would use a count() for the table as opposed to a "!=null" test? What is considered better practice. I suspect one should try to manage nulls in the properties otherwise one is writing null test code all over the place.

Thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626597/should-functions-return-null-or-an-empty-object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd be inclined to return an empty list.

At the conceptual level, null represents unknown. In your case, the orders associated with the customer are not unknown; rather, there are no orders. An empty list represents this precisely while null is imprecise and could be ambiguous--does "null" orders mean no orders or simply that the orders property hasn't yet been populated?

At the practical level, by returning an empty list, code that does computations on orders will probably need less corner-case checking. For example, a method that uses foreach to iterate through the list of orders should work just fine with a zero-length orders list (no iteration will occur) while using null for no orders will require that the method have a safety check.

Comment: Thanks for this. Very insightful. Just looked at the other SO on this, and a MS design guideline actually recommends returning empty lists and not nulls. So I have learnt something today !!

Answer (score 1):

I'll disagree with Ben; even though, he has a good point based on widely accepted theories.  While there are less error handling involved using a null return, I prefer it over an empty list because to me it seems as a wasteful use of resources.  Of course, that's a very preference-based scenario. Then again, it's really based on the overall design of your application.  Are you planning on doing anything with that list regardless of it being empty?  If so, then null would not be a way to go.  You have to decide if the ease of having a simple `.count()` check outweighs the extra lines of code you would need to write to check for null to save on resources.  As far as how much of resource saving there will be - that I don't know.  Considering you'd need to perform extra checks for null, you're trading memory for cycles.

Take what I say with a grain of salt.  I've only been programming for a year.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Interesting point about resources, but I think I will run with MS design guidelines...

Comment: @SamJolly I agree, Sam.  I just wanted to provide a different perspective.  From reading MS guidelines, Framework Design Guidelines 2nd Edition, and http://stackoverflow.com/a/1970001/2006048, it's pretty clear where my knowledge stands. :)

Comment: Although having just reading the first SO, there is plenty of null protoganists ! Why did I look ! :)

Comment: @SamJolly heh, it's just as anything else... there are always more than one side.