# Exception handling protocol for methods

Tags: java, exception

Is there any specific protocol for handling exceptions in public methods? Consider this eg.

```
public int someMethod()
{
  try{
  code that might throw an exception    
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     log the exception
  }
}
```

Say that this method might throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. So, is it correct to handle this Exception in the method itself (as in the example) or throw it and assume that the calling method will handle the Exception?

**Edit:**
Further extending my question.
Consider the following function.

```
public int[] someMethod2()
{
  try{
code that might throw an exception    
 }
catch(Exception e) {
  log the exception
  return new int[0];
 }
}
```

As in the example code above, if I return an array of size 0, then the calling method will fail with an AraryIndexOutOfBounds Exception. If I return null, then the calling method will fail with NullPointer Exception. Since, I can modify the calling method, which way is better? Should I let the calling method fail? Or should I directly call System.exit() in someMethod2()?

Is there a tutorial which explains these decisions? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175532/return-null-or-throw-exception) does not give me an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, don't handle the exception if it doesn't make sense to handle it yourself. `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` usually is a sign of a programming error, and if your app contains programming errors, crashing is the correct and responsible thing to do.

One big no-no is returning null instead of throwing exceptions, like this code:

```
public Thing getThingById(long id) {
    try {
        ResultSet rs = queryDatabase("SELECT * FROM THING WHERE ID = " + id);
        rs.next();
        return new Thing(rs.get(1), rs.get(2), rs.get(3));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, if you get `null` from this method, you don't know why. Was the ID invalid? Is the database server down? Or was it some programming error in the `queryDatabase` method?

**Edit:** Oh, and you should never log *and* rethrow, it'll just fill up your logs and make them unreadable. If you rethrow an exception, odds are that whatever code catches it further up the call chain will log it, too

Comment: Consider that the id was invalid(eg. index greater than array size). 
I have read that for public methods you should always do parameter checking first. So, by a simple if statement I find out that the index is invalid. What do I do now? throw an exception?

Comment: you should re-evaluate the design. a method should not be dependent on the caller knowing what is a valid index. post more code if you want more concrete answers.

Comment: If you can't recover from the out of bounds exception even if you tested for it beforehand then you should concentrate your efforts on the method that calls this method. At what level will you be able to handle the out of bounds exception? Is it part of a transaction that you wish to roll back? Is the code in response to a user-input? If so, then you may wish to display a dialog to the user to enter better input. At the level of the method, its better to throw the exception out where you can't handle it locally but you do have to think about where you can handle it (even if just to exit).

Comment: @athena, if you have an array, and client code requests you to do something with an element at a position that doesn't exist, it means that the client is incorrectly written - helping it crash is correct behavior.

Comment: if you can recover then handle it otherwise throw runtime exception .

Answer (score 1):

Neither. Do nothing. `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` indicates a programming error, which should either not be caught at all, or only be caught at a high level of the app. Since it'S a subclass of `RuntimeException`, you don't have to declare that the method throws it either.

This is the whole point of exceptions: you can *choose* where in the call stack to catch them, and in most cases, you should *not* catch them right where they might be thrown.

Comment: Please see my comment of the answer given by gustafc

Comment: @athena - if you detect the incorrect index before (say) an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown, then yes ... you should probably throw an appropriate exception.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on if you can catch the exception in a meaningful way, or on the code contract this method is working with, e.g. what does the caller of the method expect, etc

Comment: someMethod() is a getter method, i.e. it just returns the value of some private variable. Hence, the calling function expects the value of the variable. If I handle the exception in the method and return, say -1, then I again have to check the value returned by the this function.

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely for you to decide. If the purpose of the method is safe access to an array, you should handle it in that method. But if you are doing something totally different, you should rethrow. Good way to think about error handling is to handle the error where it is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I usually handle everything that is possible as locally as possible and the vast majority of exceptions are both expected and recoverable in my experience. Sometimes locally does not have to mean the same method and there is nothing to feel ashamed of of throwing an exception out of a method where it cannot be handled.

Additionally, I usually identify a level in the program where I want to handle the exceptions that I could not handle elsewhere. This may be the top level, or somewhere in the middle of the current stack where a partial recovery can be made.

Usually this handling simply involves logging the non-expected exception and closing down the application gracefully (in the case of non-interactive applications) or terminating the current thread of execution in more interactive applications.

The way of handling this exception is heavily application-specific but you should always start with a catch-all at your top level that will log Exceptions and Errors no matter what then write additional handlers at areas in your application where Exceptions may be recoverable.

You should never try to recover from an Error however but you may still wish to catch them (seperately) for purposes of graceful shutdown (although this is not guarenteed in the case of Errors).

Comment: Please see my comment on the answer given by gustafc

Comment: Can someone explain the vote-down here? My advice was to write a top-level catch-all handler that logs the exception no matter what, then to write handlers at the applicable level. As far as I am aware, this is standard practice and strongly advisable.

I never advised suppressing exceptions or handling Throwables or any of the standard bad practices.

I'll try not to feel hurt here :)