# Shall I design the following API using null returned value, or checked exception, or possible null object pattern

Tags: java

I come to an API `getStock` designed, where I have no good judgment, on how I should deal with failure of operation.

The API will enable me to pass a stock code, and return a stock if success.

Shall I use `null returned value` to indicate failure of operation, or `throwing checked exception` to indicate failure of operation? Or possible [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)? Why?

---

**Null Returned Value**

```
// User force to check the returned value each time.
// This happen when, stock server is down, network is down, 
// stockCode is not valid...
Stock stock = stockServer.getStock(stockCode);
if (stock != null) {
    // Success.
}
```

---

**Checked Exception**

```
try {
    // User force to catch the exception each time.
    // This happen when, stock server is down, network is down,
    // stockCode is not valid...
    Stock stock = stockServer.getStock(stockCode);
    // Success.
} catch (StockNotFoundException ex) {
}
```

---

**Null Object Pattern**

```
Stock stock = stockServer.getStock(stockCode);
// stock.getPrice(), stock.getVolume() will return 0...
// But when there is a need to check whether we are getting
// a null stock, we need to check 
// if (stock.getPrice() == 0.0 && stock.getVolume()...
```

Comment: Go with null. http://www.cs.oberlin.edu/~jwalker/nullObjPattern/  btw, jStock seems impressive. just downloaded it ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return 'null' or throw exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175532/return-null-or-throw-exception)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice when it comes to this sort of (subjective) design decision is to go with the grain of the language (i.e. try and follow the practices used by the standard library of the language.)  The Java standard library usually prefers exceptions for error handling, rather than return values.  For example, the Java `Socket` class throws an `IOException` if it cannot connect (e.g. if the network is down, or the remote address is invalid).

Null return values, on the other hand, are usually used in cases where, for example, a Collection object is unable to find a specified key.

So I think, in your case, an exception is more "in the spirit" of the Java language, because it could indicate a serious problem such as a network error.

You could also use a `null` return value to indicate that the specified `stockCode` does not exist, and an Exception to indicate a more serious problem, such as a down network.  Although, this will require users of your API to check for a null return value *and* handle the exception.

Comment: Or can I say, `return null` when there is higher chance for failure. `throw exception` when the chance for failure is lower.

Answer (score 3):

I would say do a mixture. Throw an exception for errors (stock server is down, network is down, etc) and return null if the code cannot be found. This is consistent with other Java error handling. Collections return null if there is no value associated with the key (not unlike no stock associated with the symbol) and sockets throw exceptions when the network is down. Note: I clearly used the examples from @Charles's answer.

Comment: But, isn't that will be extremely cumbersome? Caller have to do 2 things. try...catch and check for null.

Comment: @Yan: Those are two different situations: an expected output and an error situation. Therefore they should be handled differently.

Comment: @fish I think they are pretty fuzzy and there is no clear cut. For example, I use Socket's connect. I can `expect` a network connection problem. But Java people treat it as exception.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of [Return 'null' or throw exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175532/return-null-or-throw-exception).

As the absence of a stock code is not an error, I suggest not throwing an exception. In order not to test for `null` all over the place, implementing the [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) might be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

When it is an expected case that the stock you are looking for does not exist, use return null;

If it is really an exception to the normal workflow, use the exception.

Exception handling is really expensive and should only be used to handle an unexpected situation.

hth

Mario