# Return values, throw exceptions and rolling back transactions

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, try-catch, return-value

The whole "when to throw exception or return value" questions has been asked a lot (see the following to see just one example):

[Should a retrieval method return 'null' or throw an exception when it can't produce the return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175532/return-null-or-throw-exception)

and I completely agree with the answers in main.

Now my question arises from adding a little more context to the above when applying this to a more complex system. Ill try and keep this as brief and simple as possible.

Right we have an example MVC PHP application:

Model A: has a function get_car($id) which returns a car object.

Controller A has a simple function for say showing a car to the user

Controller B however has a complex function that say gets the car, modify it (say through one of model A's set functions) and also updates other tables based on some of these new values through other models and libraries throughout the system - very complex ay lol

we now get to the main part of my question:

For data integrity I want to use MySQL transactions. This is where I run into a "what's best / what's best practice" scenario...

We write Model A to return FALSE if the car is not found or there is an SQL error.
This is fine for Controller A as it just wants to know if there was a error and bom out, so we just check the return value an bom - fine.

We now get to Controller B. Controller B say does some database updating before the Model A function is called which we need to roll back on error so we need to use a transactions. now this is where I get to my problem. do I leave Model A as a return value and just check it or do I change it to throw exception with the knock on effect of then having to also re-write Controller A as we now need to catch the exception... then (not done yet ;o)) do I roll back in the catch of the model (but how do we know if a transaction has been used or not?) or do we catch and re-throw or allow to bubble up to the controller catch and do the roll back there?

what I'm trying to say is that if I have lots of models and controllers with database interaction should I just make them throw exceptions and then wrap all my other code eg controller functions in try catches encase the model or library functions ever throw, or, do I make the models "self contained" to tidy and handle there own problems but then what do I do about rolling back a transaction if (for this "call") one was open (as per my example above not every time is a transaction opened...)? if this was the case I would have to make all my functions return something and then check this in the controller, as this is the only place that knows if there is an open transaction or not...

So to clarify I can use a try catch to catch and roll back in a controller, that's ok, but how to I do this from "further down" eg in a model or library function... that could be called both during and transaction or just as an auto commit normal MySQL call?

An explained answer would be great (as I like to understand why I am doing something) but if not a some vote for the favourite of the follow solutions (well the solutions I can see):

1) make all model and library functions always return a value and then the controller can either just bom or do a try catch to roll back where necessary - but meaning that I would have to check the return value of every model and library function everywhere they are used.

2) make all model and library functions throw exceptions (say on SQL error) and wrap every controller (which would call the model and library functions) in a try catch where the catch would either just bom or roll back if necessary...

also please note "bom" is push user somewhere or show a pretty error (before someone says "its bad practice to just allow your application to die..." lol)

I hope you get where Im coming from here and sorry for the long loooooong question.

Thanks in advance
Ben

Answer (score 0):

[There's a theoretical problem implicit in the "For data integrity I want to use MySQL transactions"... since MySQL historically hasn't been very ACID - PostgreSQL and Oracle both provide stronger support for ACID.  However, back to the real question...]

Both your (1) and (2) focus on exceptions versus failure-return values, but my impression is that this isn't the key part of detangling exceptions, error returns, and open transactions (and some databases support SQL exceptions as well).  Instead, I'd focus on keeping the transaction state tied to the nesting of the functions manipulating the model.  Here are some thoughts along this line:

- You will probably always have error returns from some library functions anyway, so having Model A return FALSE isn't really breaking the paradigm, nor is there anything particularly troublesome about a mix of error returns versus exceptions.  However, error returns MUST bubble up correctly - or be converted to exceptions if they go beyond what can be locally address.
- Nested transactions are the most obvious way to have one controller start a database manipulation and still call other stuff in the app that also uses transactions.  This allows a failed sub-sub-function to abort just its own part transaction and take either the error return or exception approach to bubbling the error up on the non-SQL side while the closed sub-transactions still maintain reasonable matching state.  This usually needs to be simulated in code outside of the database (this is essentially what Django does).
- Your code could start a new (potentially large) transaction, and keep track of the fact that it's already open to keep the sub-sub-functions in your code from trying to reopen it.
- In some databases, code can detect whether a transaction is already open based on the database session state, allowing you to check the DB session state instead of tracking it in code.
- Both of the above allow one to use savepoints to simulate truly nested transactions.
- One must be *very* careful to avoid calling SQL calls with implicit commits (CREATE TABLE, for example).  MySQL probably deserves a lot more caution around this issue than, say, PostgreSQL.

One way to implement the one big transaction approach is to have high-level function that initiates the transaction and then *itself* calls the top of whatever Controller B needs to do. This makes either bubbling up errors or having a special abort-transaction exception pretty straightforward.  Only the top function would call commit rather than abort if no subfunction failed and no exception was caught. Subfunctions wouldn't call commit.

Conversely, you could have all of your functions pay attention to transactional depth implemented in the non-SQL side (your code), although this is harder to set up in some languages than others (it's pretty easy using decorators in Python, for example).  This would allow any of them to call commit if they were done and the transactional depth at zero.

Hope this helps someone :-)