# Trying to get a non-existent record: What exception to throw?

Tags: java, exception, crud

I'm creating a simple CRUD class, let's call it MyItemManager. Its role is maintaining a collection of MyItem objects in a local database. I'm wondering which exception makes most sense to throw when trying to read a record that doesn't exist (by calling myItemManager.getItem(int id), and no such ID exists in the DB) Any tips / best practices? Thanks!

Comment: **RecordNotFoundException** may be?

Comment: I'm with Kevin here. Just return `null`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175532/should-a-retrieval-method-return-null-or-throw-an-exception-when-it-cant-prod?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider returning null instead of throwing exceptions. Exceptions should be reserved for "exceptional" circumstances.

Comment: this isn't an answer, its a comment

Comment: @drewmore why is it not an answer?

Comment: Technically, everything is an answer for this question! Therefore, this is not a proper question which meets the SO standards.

Comment: @KevinBrydon - sorry, I'm a little grumpy at the moment. With the edit I have no complaints :)

Comment: Of course, only return `null` if you know that the object does not exist, i.e. the DB returns an empty result set for the query. If you cannot connect to the db, for example, that would be an "exceptional circumstance".

Comment: Thanks, I needed to be reminded of this. Going with null in case of empty query result (which was my main concern) and some exceptions in other cases.