# Which exception to throw for invalid input which is valid from client perspective

Tags: java, exception

I am writing code to find and intersection of 2 lines.
When slopes of the lines are equal they dont intersect. But on the other hand an input with  slopes of equal value is completely valid.

```
public static Point calculateIntersection(Line line1, Line line2) {

    if (line1 == null || line2 == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException(" some message ");
    }

    if (line1.getConstant() == line2.getConstant()) {
        return new Point(0, line1.getConstant());
    }

    if (line1.getSlope() == line2.getSlope()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("slopes are same, the lines do not intersect.");
    }

    int x = (line2.getConstant() - line1.getConstant()) / (line1.getSlope() - line2.getSlope());
    int y = line1.getSlope() * x + line1.getConstant();

    return new Point(x, y);
}
```

The question is throwing illegal argument exception the right thing to do ? 
Since input is valid, it does not completely convince me.

Is custom exception the right thing to do ?
Sounds like a good choice but an additional opinion would help.

Thanks

Comment: Is this really an exception?  I'm all for preferring exceptions over nullable return values but in this case it would express an expected return value.

Comment: Input Mismatch Exception, Number Format Exception or in the most generic case, just add Illegal Argument Exception.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

> The question is *is throwing illegal argument exception the right thing to do?*

There is no single "right thing to do".  It depends on how you want / need to "frame" this condition; i.e. is it a bug, a user input error, or something that the program is supposed to be able to deal with?

- If the case of two lines not intersecting is unequivocally a "bug", then `IllegalArgumentException` is fine.   This is what the exception is designed for.  (Note that it is an *unchecked* exception, so the expectation is that it won't be caught / recovered from.)
- If this is a case that you expect the program to be able to recover from by itself, then a custom exception is the best idea.  That way, you reduce the possibility of your code getting confused by (say) a library method throwing (say) an `IllegalArgumentException` ... than means something other than "two lines intersected".
- If this case is something that you expect to report to the end user as part of input validation, then a generic "validation error" exception might be more appropriate than a specific custom exception.  However, this method doesn't look like it is designed to be used (solely) for user input validation.

---

In some contexts, it may be better to not throw an exception at all, but (IMO) this is not one of those contexts.

The alternatives to throwing an exception are returning `null` or returning a `Point` value that *means* "no such point" to the calling code.  The problems with these alternatives are:

- If you return `null` the application has to deal with the `null` case ... or there will be NPEs.
- There is no natural `Point` instance that could be used to mean "not a point"<sup>1</sup>.

This is not to say that you couldn't make these alternatives work.  It is just that in this context, it will *probably* be more work to do that, and *probably* there won't be a tangible pay-off.

---

<sup>1 - I am assuming `Point` is `java.awt.Point` or similar.  Obviously you *could* define and use a custom `Point` class which provides a "no such point" instance.  But it will come at a cost.  And you will need to deal with the case where code accidentally uses the "no such point" instance in some computation.  And you are probably back where you started; i.e. throwing an exception!</sup>

Answer (score 5):

This almost certainly should not throw an exception, because it makes perfect sense to invoke a method like this with any two `Line` values. You have already appropriately handled null values.

You have also, very reasonably, defined the behavior of your class in one of the ill-defined input situations, namely two coincident "constant" (horizontal) lines, where you return the point at `x=0` on that line. You ought to similarly select return values for the other cases of ill-defined inputs: coinciding vertical lines, coinciding lines that are neither horizontal nor vertical, and non-coinciding parallel lines.

In my opinion, the most natural result for the last case - non-coinciding parallel lines - would be `null`, reflecting the fact that there is no point of intersection.

It would then be up to the client to decide whether a null intersection warrants an exception, an error message, or whatever. E.g. an interactive shell prompting the user for lines to intersect would probably print an error message and ask the user to try again. Some more complicated calculation, e.g. a linear optimizer trying to define boundaries for its search, might want to throw `IllegalArgumentException` if the constraints giving rise to the parallel lines contradict each other.

Of course, the return values in all these cases (coincident lines or non-coincident parallel lines) should be precisely documented in the method's javadoc.

Answer (score 3):

**[Keep in mind that a more generic version of this question was closed as primarily opinion-based.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175532/should-a-retrieval-method-return-null-or-throw-an-exception-when-it-cant-prod)**

If it were me, I would return `null`. In most cases you should not use exception handling as a form of flow control. Returning `null` would help avoid that for any code consuming your method.

**Related Discussions:**

[Dont Use Exceptions For Flow Control](https://web.archive.org/web/20140430044213/http://c2.com/cgi-bin/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl)

[Should a retrieval method return 'null' or throw an exception when it can't produce the return value? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175532/should-a-retrieval-method-return-null-or-throw-an-exception-when-it-cant-prod)

[Are exceptions as control flow considered a serious antipattern? If so, Why?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why)

[Arguments for or against using Try/Catch as logical operators [closed]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/107723/arguments-for-or-against-using-try-catch-as-logical-operators)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say you do the right thing: you catch the condition early. It is either that or people will complain that "your program is buggy, look at this input data, division by 0".

Given that there will be no such error in 99+% of situations, this is an exceptional condition and doesn't grant declaring a checked exception, so an unchecked exception looks indeed like the right choice.

Now, as to whether `IllegalArgumentException` is the "good one", it is at least the closest exception describing this case... You can, if you feel you have a better name, always create your own one inheriting `RuntimeException`.

**IF**, on the other hand, this situation is not that infrequent, then maybe the logic to reach that function should be reviewed so as to never hit this condition in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

As @Andy-Lowry and @KamikazeCZ say, this should not be an exception.

*This* method should not concern itself with whether the client expects lines to always intersect or not; it should only bother with finding the intersection of two lines -- something which inherently might not happen.

If the caller gets back a result indicating no-intersection, then THAT code can decide whether it's invalid-input because the end-user was duly warned, or something they can handle (perhaps by re-prompting), or throw a customized exception.

So, back to what *should* this method return?  Some sort of sentinel value, the same way that `indexOf` returns -1 in the collections library.  Returning `null` is a reasonable sentinel.  In Java 8, you can return an `Optional<Point>`, to help remind the caller that there might not be a proper `Point`.

You have an additional problem, too: what somebody asks for the intersection of a line with itself?  (Mathematically, the intersection of two lines is either 0 point, 1 point, or infinitely many points.)  You might need to be able to return *two* sentinel values, which is more involved, in Java.  This method could weasel out of the situation this time, by saying "in the case of multiple answers, this method may return any of them", or (what I'd probably do) "...returns the Point nearest the origin".

Btw, this thinking largely follows from a unit-test mindset: start by defining the correct answer should be for a variety of corner-case inputs, before launching into code and kinda committing yourself to a certain return-type etc.

Finally: when comparing the results of `getSlope()` using `==`, beware floating-point roundoff errors.  It might be the best thing to do here, but it's still problematic.  The way you assume (or round) the intersection to `int`s, though, suggests you might have very special constraints/assumptions going on in your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the contract that the method has with the caller.

In general, since any line might or might not intersect, it seems to me that a  `null` is a perfectly suitable answer.  It indicates that no such point exists.

However, if there is some expectation that the point must exist:  for example the lines selected are part of a polylateral then the point is expected to exist, AND not finding the point is a general failure.  Throwing an exception in this situation saves the callling program from having to check for null and then fail itself.

It depends on the expectation of the contract.

I would not use `IllegalArgument` exception for this because two lines were supplied, and the contract is that lines will be supplied.  Generally not that non-parallel lines must be supplied.  I would throw an exception that more clearly says "Lines do not intersect" or something like that.

My rationale for whether it is an illegal argument is to ask the question "Can the calling program know whether the argument is good or not."   The calling program can easily tell if it is sending a `null` or a Line, and one should expect it to know the difference.  But the calling program would not (in this case) be expected to know that two lines are parallel.  Therefor it is more like a result, than an error.

Answer (score -2):

Exceptions should be used to catch errors in program flow ("what happens inside") , not for input validation. I wouldn't throw an exception at all.
Think about it, this is not what "exception" means as it is completely normal for the user to input two lines with equal slopes.

Comment: Look at the next line: this is either that or a division by 0

Comment: When the user enters two same slopes, of course you won't continue and divide by zero, you'll warn him and stop instead. Throwing an exception is not a good idea because it... well... isn't an exception. It's completely normal.
This is what the if-statement is for.

Comment: Oh yeah? The user expects a _result_. And the result of an intersection.

Comment: The user expects a result or, if you can't give a result, the error message that he understands. Throwing an exception:
1) doesn't correspond to what exceptions are made for
2) might not be as readable
3) includes some overhead, which is not so bad in this case but it can be in some others