# What's the Correct Way to Shutdown a Condition Variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

A coworker recently asked for my opinions on a thread safe queue class he is modifying.  A shortened version of the waitAndPop method is below:

```
std::shared_ptr<T> waitAndPop() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);
    dataCond.wait(lock, [this] { return (!dataQueue.empty() || !queueAlive);});

    if (dataQueue.empty() || !queueAlive)
        return std::shared_ptr<T>(); // NULL

    std::shared_ptr<T> result = dataQueue.front();
    dataQueue.pop();
    return result;
}
```

A common dilemma with these sorts of classes is how to handle breaking out of the condition wait on shutdown.  In this case, he eventually returns a null pointer.  Returning null pointers from modern C++ seems clunky and outdated to me and places a burden on the user.  I'd prefer throwing an exception or ignore it altogether, forcing the user to cooperatively shutdown.

My question is what's the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175532