# Handling case of no path exists for path planning

Tags: java

I'm programming an implementation of incremental phi* in Java which is an algorithm designed to find any-angle paths in 3D space. The most important method in my api is `LinkedHashSet<Point> planPath()`. Obviously there are cases where there are no possible paths. Everything works and I'm able to detect when a path doesn't exist, but I'm not sure how my API should relay this event to the user. I could either throw an exception, change the return type to `Optional<LinkedHashSet<Point>>`, or return `null`. I'm not sure what the best case is. Also if I were to throw an exception, should it be a checked exception?

Comment: I think this is primarily opinion based, but it may also be a duplicate of [Should a retrieval method return 'null' or throw an exception when it can't produce the return value?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/175532/1945631)

Answer (score 0):

Well, my general rule when creating a public API is to favor to return an empty collection rather than to return a `null` value.

The reason is because, the collection class has the `isEmpty()` function to check whether it has any value or not. and also, the `Optional` class is only exists after java 1.8. So, I don't think it is a good idea to use that class.

because it is not an error, I don't think that throwing an exception can be meaningful here :).