# When is it correct to return a null reference type in C#

Tags: c#, reference, null, pass-by-reference

I have a C# method that is expected to return an object. I would prefer if this method does not throw any exceptions.

My question is, is it acceptable to let the method return null and therefore give the null check responsibility to the caller without further warning?

Should the called assume that the object may be null, simply because it is a reference type? (And the default value of reference types are null: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/null )

Please see my example below

```
// this method is expected to return an object
public MyClass getObject()
{
  MyClass myObject = null;
  // Another option would be to initialize to a new instance, calling the default constructor and not setting any properties 
  // MyClass myObject = new MyClass(); // no null check needed by the caller, but it is a pretty useless object 

  try
  {
    // just as an example  
    myObject = new MyClass();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
  }
  return myObject; // will return null when and exception occured
}

public class MyClass
{
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe there is a right or wrong answer to this, as long as you're consistent and comment why the value might be null before you check for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should a retrieval method return 'null' or throw an exception when it can't produce the return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/175532/11683)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can return `null` likewise you are currently doing and in which case the responsibility lies to caller to check for nullity before trying to access any of the property of the object. Using C# 6 syntax

```
muobject?.Age
```

Per pattern you can use `Null Object Pattern`; in which case you return an empty object instead of returning `null`. Thus even if caller mistakes it won't blow up with a `NullRefException`. For validation purpose you can check for the property value like `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(myobject.name)) ....`

Comment: Of course he can but he asks if it's good to return null or better throw the exception/return a defualt object. If he documents the behaviour and is consistent with similar methods then any approach is fine.