# Error when splitting a string in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to convert a floating point binary into a decimal number and i am struggling on how to split the mantissa up into two.

I have the following lines but not sure if it is correct:

```
 Dim mantissaarray() As String = Split(mantissa,,T)
 Dim first As Integer = CInt(mantissaarray(0))
 Dim second As Integer = CInt(mantissaarray(1))
```

the third line is where there is an error

> **System.IndexOutOfRangeException:** 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Could someone tell me what i am doing wrong to get this error as i do not understand?

The mantissa is a string e.g 0110 and T is an integer e.g 2
Output to the array should be a split of the string by the third number e.g 01 and 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should a retrieval method return 'null' or throw an exception when it can't produce the return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175532/should-a-retrieval-method-return-null-or-throw-an-exception-when-it-cant-prod)

Comment: Can you be more precise on what you mean by "mantissa is a binary string"? Do you have an example?

Comment: What is the content of `mantissa`? What is `T`? You're splitting on white space. Is that correct? What is `Option Compare` set to?

Comment: the mantissa is a string e.g 0110

Comment: T is a number eg 2

Comment: i don't know what you mean by option compare

Comment: You cannot split on white space when there are no white spaces. You can write something like `dim mantissaarray() = mantissa.Select(Function(c) CInt(c.ToString())).ToArray()`

Comment: what is .select it  creates an error

Comment: It looks like you want the [String.Substring Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8) rather than splitting the string; the latter is normally taken to mean splitting it at occurrences of a particular character.

Comment: It's a [Language Integrated Query (LINQ)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/introduction-to-linq). You can add a Reference to `System.Linq` in the Project or add `Imports System.Linq` to a class.

Comment: Base on your edit, you cannot expect to have that string split into an array of Integers. You can split the string into an array of strings. You could write something like: `dim mantissaarray() = {mantissa.Substring(0, 2), mantissa.Substring(2)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A String in .net is an array of Char. So, using this fact we can do one of the following.

```
Private Sub OpCode()
    Dim mantissa = "0110"
    'The Linq way
    Dim intArray = (From c In mantissa
                    Select CInt(c.ToString)).ToArray
    For Each i In intArray
        Debug.Print(i.ToString)
    Next
    'The For Each way
    Dim intArray2(mantissa.Length - 1) As Integer
    Dim index As Integer
    For Each c As Char In mantissa
        intArray2(index) = CInt(c.ToString)
        index += 1
    Next
    For Each i In intArray2
        Debug.Print(i.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

Same result.

Comment: i want to split the string by a certain number stored in variable T.